# Flag SEEN not working with Yahoo! Mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, yahoo, pop3

I am using the JavaMail API to fetch mails. Earlier today I succeeded in doing so with Gmail. Now I tried Yahoo Mail and it worked too.

One problem though:

It doesn't show if the mail has been read or not correctly. I have a mailbox full of mails that have been read, though the application says I haven't.

I use this to determine if a mail that is fetched, have been read or not:

```
 String isRead = (message[i].getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

It works with Gmail. Just not with Yahoo Mail.
Anyone got any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What protocols are you using? I know Gmail supports IMAP so I assume that is what you are using there. Does Yahoo? If they only support POP3 then the flags won't work because POP3 doesn't support flags.

Try seeing what Folder.getPermanentFlags() returns.

Comment: Gmail and AOL supports IMAP, but Yahoo (and now Hotmail as I discovered) use POP3. What I did to "solve" the problem, is to add a Date indicator in my application, so you can see when you received the email at least, and then determine whether you think it's new or not.

Comment: The best you can do with POP3 is show messages as new that weren't previously downloaded. See the programming notes about getting message UIDs so you can keep track of what was already downloaded at http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/POP3-README.txt

Answer (score 0):

Uh, Yahoo mail is broken?

If you set the flag, does it stay set?

You believe the message have been read by looking at the web mail interface, right?  Does setting the flag change anything in the web mail interface?

Comment: But, I am not really manipulating the mails that I fetch. I just read the information about them. Who they are from, the subject and if they have been read by you or not.